# Show all posts of all categories but excluding a category on custom blog page with pagination of my theme

Tags: plugins, categories, query-posts, recent-posts

```
  <h3>Recent Posts</h3>
  <?php // Display blog posts on any page @ http://m0n.co/l
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null;
    $category_id = get_cat_ID('Tour');
    $wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('showposts=6' . '&paged='.$paged);
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();    if(in_category($category_id)){?>
    <div class="blog" style="display:none;">
        <time datetime="2013-01-01"><?php echo date("j"); ?><br>
<?php echo strtoupper(substr(date("F"),0,3)); ?></time>
<div class="extra_wrapper">
      <div class="text1 upp">
   <?php the_title(); ?> </div>
    </div>
     <div class="clear"></div>
    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) { ?> <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'img_inner fleft')); ?> <?php } ?>
    <div class="extra_wrapper">
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    <br>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn">Details</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

please give a suitable guidance for that customization in retrieve posts of all category exclude one category post in Wordpress custom theme. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the category parameters of [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), you'll see that you can use either `cat=-12` or `category__not_in' => 12` to exclude a category with ID 12 in your custom query.

I just also want to point out a few things here. `showposts` is depreciated, you should be using `posts_per_page`. Also `'showposts=6' . '&paged='.$paged` is wrong. You should just use `&` between your parameters. So you should do something like this `'posts_per_page=6&paged='.$paged`

To conclude, to exclude the category 'Tour', which is what I presume from your code, you can do change this line

```
$wp_query->query('showposts=6' . '&paged='.$paged);
```

to

```
$wp_query->query('posts_per_page=6&cat=-' . $category_id . '&paged='.$paged);
```